# Remmina doesn't connect

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

After returning from vacation I began to get the error message in Remmina when connecting to corporate RDP server:

```
The Remote Desktop Gateway "a.b.c" denied the user "domain\user" access due to policy.
```

Not sure what could have caused it - ubuntu software update which could include Remmina update or some changes in the configuration of RDP server...
Is it possible to get more detailed information about the error. Or does it definitely indicate the changes on the side of the corporate RDP server?

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is pretty much the extent of the error - that message in Remmina [occurs when it receives error code 0x800759DB](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/blob/master/plugins/rdp/rdp_plugin.c), which is [described in Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsgu/84cd92e4-592c-4219-95d8-18021ac654b0) as "Returned when the RDG server denies the RDG client access due to policy."

You'll need to reach out to the administrator on your company's side and see what policies have changed (or perhaps let them know that their policies unintentionally changed!), and potentially adapt your RDP configuration accordingly.

Comment: I contacted the HelpDesk. We use 2FA authorization. They told me that I didn't scan both QR-codes in Alladin app. That solved the issue.